# Unix timestamp being interpreted incorrectly by JavaScript Date()

Tags: angular, date, firebase, ionic-framework, timestamp

I create the date like this, with a timestamp retrieved from firebase:

```
let da = new Date(item.date.day);
```

I have verified that `item.date.day` is a timestamp, and the correct timestamp.

However, it always creates the date:

`Sun Jan 18 1970 03:53:45 GMT-0500 (EST)`

No matter what the timestamp is. I have checked the timestamps [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/), here they are:

`1500825600
1499097600
1500134400
1501084800`

They are all dates in July as they should be (these are the values for `item.date.day`).

Extremely bizarre. Any help is much needed and appreciated.

Comment: Multiple by 1000: you're storing them in seconds, but `Date` expected milliseconds. `new Date(1500825600*1000)` => `Sun Jul 23 2017 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, `new Date(value)` expects value to be in [milliseconds since "1 January 1970 00:00:00"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

If you multiply your unix timestamps (seconds since "1 January 1970 00:00:00") with 1000, you will get the correct results.